# Compiling Freetype 2 for an iPad application in Xcode 4

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode4, freetype2, podofo

Can any one tell me how to compile Freetype 2 in Xcode 4? I went through a lot of blogs but none of them are very clear.

I want to use the PoDoFo library for modifying PDF metadata, and PoDoFo requires Freetype 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found the solution:

use macPort to install freetype !